# Why and when does D3 resolve links in a force diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have found that in a force diagram when I look at my data after a bit that some of the links, which have a source and target id instead have the full data of the node inside of them. Why is that and when does this step happen?

Comment: Can you share the example to provide something to work with in an answer?

Comment: no at the moment, I'm trying to replicate it, but d3 will replace the ids with the node information